# Entity framework SqlQuery failing with no reason (ObjectDisposedException)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a method where two SQL queries take place, for example:

```
public async Task<Result> SomeMethod(string p1, string p2)
{
    Context.Database.CommandTimeout = 60;

    var param1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8);
    param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    var param2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8);
    param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    var param3 = new SqlParameter("@param3", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    param3.Value = DBNull.Value;
    var param4 = new SqlParameter("@param4", SqlDbType.BigInt);
    param4.Value = DBNull.Value;

    var result1 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
                new SqlParameter("@param1", p1), param1, param2
                ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var result2 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
               new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
               ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return new Result { Result1 = result1, Result2 = result2 };
}
```

Don't mind variable names that's just an example. The problem is that the second query doesn't execute and throws error:

> "System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been
> disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a
> connection.'"

Both queries are working. If I swap queries the second one is always failing. I have no idea why the second query is not working. I've googled the error and found out that it usually appears when you try to assign query result to some entity and use it outside the context scope what fails because of lazy-load of EF but here the string  is returned form the procedure, not entity. I see no reasons why context should dispose after the first query.

Please ask me for any details.

Comment: On the contrary, there's a very clear reason that suggests EF is misused (which it is, EF is an ORM not a replacement for ADO.NET). `SomeMethod` is using a global `DbContext` instance that's already been disposed. If you want to call a stored procedure from a DbContext put the code in the `DbContext` class itself and use its built-in methods to execute SQL queries instead of going through the database connection. In EF Core you can use `FromSql`, `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PanagiotisKanavos, I know some techniques there may be used  not on purpose but still it's so strange that after the first query is executed the context is disposed  without any prerequisites. That looks very unclear to me, is there any way I can fix it without making big changes in the current implementation?

Comment: It's not strange at all, it's quite clear. Where does `Context` come from? Is it a static property that was disposed? Is this used in an ASP.NET controller? Injected DbContexts are disposed as soon as a request completes. The fix is to put the method in the context class to begin with, removing any uncertainty about whether it's trying to work with a dead context or not.

Comment: You haven't posted the code that creates `Context` so one can only guess what's going on. The only certain thing is that `Context` was created and then disposed *explicitly*. This didn't happen by accident

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Context comes from the ```EfRepositoryBase``` which is inherited in the class where SomeMethod is located. The problem is that it's not disposed until the first query is executed. I think I can't use ```FromSql``` etc because these methods are used on a particular DbSet but I don't retrieve any data which is connected with DbSet's entities. Do you mean that I should put SomeMethod in DbContext - the class where all DbSets are defined?

Comment: The class where all *access methods* are defined. The very name `EfRepositoryBase` suggests you're trying to use the "generic" repository *antipattern* and probably storing an instance of a DbContext that despite the comments, is explicitly disposed. You don't need an `EfRepositoryBase`, a *DbSet* is a repository already. The DbContext is the Unit-of-Work. Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for Unit-of-Work and Repository with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/). The problem isn't in EF Core

Comment: To put it another way, if DbContext was automagically disposed people would have noticed years ago. In all similar errors, the problem is that the DbContext was used after disposal. In ASP.NET Core web apps this occurs when a DbContext injected through DI is used *after* an action completes. DbContexts are registered as scoped objects and get disposed when a request completes

Comment: Another common cause is trying to use a scoped service like a DbContext from a *singleton* service, eg a BackgroundService. When that instance is disposed, the singleton is left with a dead object.  This is explained in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

Comment: @Storm, your method looks good. Common problem in such cases that you have missed `await` somewhere in other place.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using ```EfRepositoryBase``` to execute a procedure. For this purpose I can use either the Repository or DbSet. I don't use DbSet because it is bounded to the particular entity but in the method I am trying to execute a procedure rather than getting entity form the database. I've reviewed the links you posted, it's great that I can enhance the behavior of the application but I can't see how it should solve my problem. You've said that Context is dispose after request. So how does it execute the first query if it's already disposed?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this error is associated with lazy loading which has no bearing in this usage. My suspicion is the `async` nature of the code.

First try making the first call synchronous:

```
var result1 = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
            new SqlParameter("@param1", p1), param1, param2
            ).FirstOrDefault();

var result2 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
           new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
           ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If that works, switch to make the second call synchronous:

```
var result1 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
            new SqlParameter("@param1", p1), param1, param2
            ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var result2 = Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
           new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
           ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'd expect if the first worked, the second would still fail. Then try adding a "dummy" call ahead of the first:

```
var dummy2 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
           new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
           ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var result1 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
            new SqlParameter("@param1", p1), param1, param2
            ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var result2 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
           new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
           ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If this fails reliably on the `result1` execution then it would seem that SqlQuery may have a bug, potentially threading related. If this is the case, or in doubt, you should be able to work around this by explicitly scoping your DbContext for each call:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8);
param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
var param2 = new SqlParameter("@param2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8);
param2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
var param3 = new SqlParameter("@param3", SqlDbType.BigInt);
param3.Value = DBNull.Value;
var param4 = new SqlParameter("@param4", SqlDbType.BigInt);
param4.Value = DBNull.Value;

string result1, result2;

using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
{
    result1 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
            new SqlParameter("@param1", p1), param1, param2
            ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
using (var context = ContextFactory.Create())
{
    result2 = await Context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("[Some_Procedure] @param1,@param2,@param3",
           new SqlParameter("@param1", p2), param3, param4
           ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
return new Result { Result1 = result1, Result2 = result2 };
```

Where ContextFactory is a new dependency injected into this service that can create a new DbContext.

Comment: While I'd agree with @PanagiotisKanavos that this isn't the right way to go with EF Core (use the `FromSQL...` methods), I was _doing_ that, and still getting this error. You're 100% right that going synchronous eliminated my error